# Installing Qt5 and PyQt5 for Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt5, pyqt5

I am new to Stack Overflow and Python.

I am developing for Visual Effects, which means that I am (and will continue) using Python 2.7. I'm a bit lost and looking for clear instructions on how to install `pyqt5`. I know this seems pretty elementary, so I appreciate everyone's patience.

There is a lot of information on this subject like, you need `QT5` or `Scintilla`? A lot of the instructions are fragmented and don't have all of the information. I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with clear and concise instructions.

For example:

1. Install Python 2.7
2. Install *x*
3. ...
4. ...
5. ...

I'm willing to figure it out myself, but I feel the information I have has a lot of holes and could use some help/direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also do I need qt5 and then the binding pyqt5 or are they unrelated?

Comment: Like here is something that I found but none of this makes any sense to me

https://riverbankcomputing.com/pipermail/pyqt/2016-December/038450.html

I mean what folder does the sip zip get unpacked to...Everytime I find something like this it seems like there are soooo many details missing and nothing works.

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: PyQt5 does not have an official release for Python 2.7. You will need to [build it from source](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html#building-and-installing-from-source). This requires Qt5 to be installed

Answer (score -2):

Maybe [this link](http://projects.skylogic.ca/blog/how-to-install-pyqt5-and-build-your-first-gui-in-python-3-4/) can help. It is for installing PyQt5 on Python 3, but I think it will be the same process for Python 2.

Update:
Since you didn't say any specific OS, I will assume you're using Windows. For Windows, there is already Python distribution which is ready to use such as [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io/). This is what I've done on my machine:

1. Download appropriate WinPython version for your machine,
2. Download appropriate [PyQt5 wheels](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyqt5-tools) version for your machine,
3. Install WinPython,
4. Extract the downloaded PyQt5 wheels,
5. Copy **pyqt5-tools** folder found **inside** where you extracted PyQt5 wheels
6. Paste it to Where_You_Installed_WinPython\Lib\site-packages.

You can start designing your GUI with double-clicking **Qt Designer.exe**. After you finished designing your GUI, you can convert the GUI file (with `*.ui` extension) to `*.py` with `pyuic5 -x yourgui.ui -o yourgui.py` command.

`python` and `pyuic5` command on your command prompt can only be executed in your WinPython installation folder. inside your WinPython installation folder.